# minFractionDigits & maxFractionDigits on angularjs1

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I filter numbers with `minFractionDigits` and `maxFractionDigits` on angularjs1?

Angular2 has the decimal pipe filter as [described here](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe).

> `number_expression | number[:digitInfo]`
>
> Formats a number as text. Group sizing and separator and other
>   locale-specific configurations are based on the active locale.
>
> where `expression` is a number:
>
> - `digitInfo` is a string which has a following format: 
>     {`minIntegerDigits`}.{`minFractionDigits`}-{`maxFractionDigits`}
> - `minIntegerDigits` is the minimum number of integer digits to use.
>     Defaults to 1.
> - `minFractionDigits` is the minimum number of digits after
>     fraction. Defaults to 0.
> - `maxFractionDigits` is the maximum number of digits after fraction. Defaults to 3.

I would like to do this on angularjs1.
How can I do this?

Comment: the closest that AngularJs comes to is the `fractionSize` parameter of the `number` filter.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number, unless you write your own custom filter.

Comment: I know `fractionSize` parameter. I would like to set `minFractionSize` and `maxFractionSize` as `0-2`

Comment: those aren't options built in to AngularJs.  You'll have to write your own custom filter to handle the logic.

Comment: Angular2 uses `Intl.NumberFormat` internally in it's pipe.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat.   https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.4/packages/common/src/pipes/intl.ts#L36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a custom filter as below with @Claies advice.

```
angular.module('MyApp', []).filter('numberMinMaxFractionSize',function () {
    return function (num, min, max) {
        if (typeof num === "number") {
            var options = {
                minimumFractionDigits: min,
                maximumFractionDigits: max,
            }
            return new Intl.NumberFormat(findLocale(), options).format(num);
        } else {
            return num;
        }
    };
});

function findLocale() {
    try {
        return (navigator.browserLanguage || navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage)
    } catch (e) {
        return "en-US";
    }
}
```

html:

```
<div>{{value |numberMinMaxFractionSize:0:2}}</div>
```